# Is there anyone left in the world, save me and my rifle?

Tags: under-the-garden

I've been playing [Under the Garden](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=13394.0) and, while exploring has been quite enjoyable, I've begun to feel a tinge of loneliness as I wander the vast pixelated landscape all by myself.

This feeling was somewhat lessened when I met Jerry, my hunting rifle, but I've recently made a discovery that suggests that there may be someone else to talk to in this lonely world:

[image: evidence]

It may be a false hope, but I can't help but wonder:

#### Is there anyone else in this "garden", save Jerry and I?

Answer (score 2):

No one else exists and it does get lonely sometimes. You will find those messages of "It appears someone has lived here" however no one exists but you.